# Laravel Migration Error: "Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR: no schema has been selected to create"

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am facing an issue while trying to run Laravel migrations with PostgreSQL. When I execute the php artisan migrate command, I encounter the following error:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in at character 14 (Connection: pgsql, SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial not null primary key, "migration" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null))`

**Details:**

- Laravel version: 10
- PostgreSQL version: psql (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Ubuntu 14.10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
- Operating System: Wsl 2 Ubuntu

Checked and confirmed the PostgreSQL connection details in the .env file.
Verified that the specified database user has the necessary permissions.
Ensured that the public schema (default in Laravel) exists in the PostgreSQL database.
Migration File Example:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateExampleTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('example', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            // ... other columns
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('example');
    }
}
`
```